Can I use two UiComponents in same layout file to create admin grid?
I am trying to create a page which consist of the form and also the admin grid. Is it possible to do that. If so, can anybody provide documentation

Yes you can add your ui form and listing file in your layout in following way :
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <!-- <update handle="styles"/> -->
    <body>
      <referenceContainer name="content">
        <uiComponent name="your_ui_form"/>
        <uiComponent name="your_ui_listing"/>
      </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>

Attaching screenshot for reference :


How can I use the values entered in the form to alter the values in listing grid?

Could you explain the full workflow and what you intend to achieve with the aforementioned form? Additionally, please provide examples of how it will affect the grid.

Like in the report dashboards, We can fill out the form and related values will be filled in the grid right. I want to achieve the same thing.

Yes, it's possible to create a page in Magento 2 that consists of both a form and an admin grid. You can do it using the below way.

Create the Form: You can create a form UI component by defining it in a UI Component XML file. This file specifies the fields, fieldsets, and data sources for your form.

Create the Admin Grid: Similarly, create an admin grid UI component by defining it in another UI Component XML file. This file will configure the grid's columns, data source, and other settings.



view/adminhtml/ui_component/my_form.xml
view/adminhtml/ui_component/my_grid.xml


Link the Form and Grid to Your Layout: In your layout XML file, use the <uiComponent> node to include both the form and grid UI components on your page.

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <uiComponent name="my_form"/>
        <uiComponent name="my_grid"/>
    </body>
</page>

This layout XML file tells Magento to render both UI components (my_form and my_grid) on the same page. Each UI component will be rendered according to its own XML configuration, which defines the grid or form structure, data source, columns, fields, etc.
Keep in mind that when including multiple UI components on the same page, you should ensure that their configurations do not conflict.

If you like the answer, please support by approving or upvoting the answer. Thanks!
